# Calculating Age from Birthdate TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of birthdates - and I am interested in calculating age from the birth year. I do have some null values in the birthdate column, but thinking I will calculate the age for all records where I do have a birthdate, then fill in null values with the median age.

I am getting a TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

Birthdates are in ISO format - initially objects, but I've converted them to datetime.

```
from datetime import date

final_df['D_O_B__c'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['D_O_B__c'], format = "%Y-%m-%d", errors = 'coerce')

final_df['D_O_B__c'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['D_O_B__c']).dt.date

def calculate_age(born):
    born = datetime.strptime(born, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

final_df['Age'] = df['D_O_B__c'].apply(calculate_age)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-14316b1ee715> in <module>
----> 1 final_df['Age'] = final_df['D_O_B__c'].apply(calculate_age)

~\anaconda3\envs\syml_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4211             else:
   4212                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4213                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4214 
   4215         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-75-ad9c7faf42c0> in calculate_age(born)
      1 def calculate_age(born):
----> 2     born = datetime.strptime(born, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
      3     today = date.today()
      4     return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float
```

Any advice on where I am going wrong here? Is it due to the null value records or...?

Comment: Yes `NaN` is a float so it doesn't have any of the attributes that a string would. You can add some basic handling like: `if pd.isnull(born): return np.NaN; else: your calculation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting in and out of dates / datetimes a few too many times

`final_df['D_O_B__c'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['D_O_B__c'], format = "%Y-%m-%d", errors = 'coerce')`
Once you've run this line, the column is now a pandas Datetime dtype

`final_df['D_O_B__c'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['D_O_B__c']).dt.date`
this line is unnecessary

In the calculate age function, you don't need to use datetime.strptime since the supplied object will already be a datetime, so your function can be simplified to

```
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

And now this line will run just fine, returning NAs for rows with bad/null timestamp strings originally

`final_df['Age'] = df['D_O_B__c'].apply(calculate_age)`

To fill those values in with the median age, you can just do
`final_df.loc[final_df['Age'].isnull(),'Age'] = final_df['Age'].median()`

which calculates the median 'Age' value for non-null rows, and then sets all null rows to that value